# How to import failed sync from G Shock to Strava?

Tags: watch, strava, fitness

Some of the runs recorded in G-Shock GBD-H1000 synced to Move app but failed to get into Strava. How do I sync the failed runs?

Answer (score 0):

Please go to the following link to access G-SHOCK MOVE for WEB:

https://cws.casio-intl.com/landing.html

Settings - link your account to Strava or Google Fit.

- You must register a Casio ID to use apps and web-based services. For more information about Casio IDs, see this page.

Comment: That is something I used to do. But some of the runs failed to sync and there is no way I could fix it even with reinstalls of the app or relinking the two apps.